# iam user not able to write to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

i have this policy, why is it not able to write to s3 bucket

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-erb4urdcaiht-us-east-1",
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-008151213029",
    "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-for-iam"
    ]
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:PutObject*",
    "s3:GetObject*",
    "s3:GetObjectAcl",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:DeleteObject"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-erb4urdcaiht-us-east-1",
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-008151213029",
    "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-for-iam"
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

when i try to upload object i get, i have given putobject why iam i getting this error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: Try removing the asterisk after `PutObject` and `GetObject`. Instead add a slash and asterisk to the end of the resources in the same block, e. g. `"arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-for-iam/*`

Comment: Thank you, i should have realised it, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
"arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-erb4urdcaiht-us-east-1"
```

to this

```
"arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-erb4urdcaiht-us-east-1/*"
```

worked in my case.